# float left property not working in syncfusion HTML to PDF conversion

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, pdf, pdf-generation

i am using syncfusion pdf reporting in my html code css property float left property which i am applied on div not working please give any suggesstion

this is my code

```
"<div name=\"divname\" style=\"width: 450px; float: left; text-align: right; height: 30px;\">"+
                "<div style=\"width: 100px; text-align: right; height: 30px; float: left; position: relative;\">"+
                    "<span>Client Name: </span>"+
                "</div>"+
                "<div style=\"width: 325px; padding-left: 10px; text-align: left; height: 30px; position: relative; float: left;\">"+
                    "1233"+
                "</div>"+
            "</div>"+
            "<div name=\"divcompany\" style=\"width: 450px; float: left; text-align: right; height: 30px;\">"+
                "<div style=\"width: 100px; text-align: right; height: 30px; float: left; position: relative;\">"+
                    "<span>Company: </span>"+
                "</div>"+
                "<div style=\"width: 325px; padding-left: 10px; text-align: left; height: 30px; position: relative; float: left;\">"+
                     "1233"+
                "</div>"+
            "</div>"+
```

Answer (score 0):

The Syncfusion Essential PDF uses the Internet explorer web browser control to render the html file into PDF document by generating EMF. The PDF document will appear as same as the HTML file rendered in IE browser.

You have aligned the text to right, make the text-align property to “left” to make your div content align to left.

Regards,
George